# Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4402/49).**

---

Anime & Manga is scheduled for an election [next week, October 19, 2020](https://anime.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until October 19, 2020 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Would it be ok to copy questions for another site’s mod election, or is it preferred to come up with original questions?

Comment: Questions from other sites' election or from previous elections here are both fine

Answer (score 6):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 4):

A user has posted a question which by itself is fine and is answerable, however the user's actions involving the question has been troubling (ie. spamming non-answers, spamming the question link in comments across the site, defacing edits, harassing/abusive behavior to other users who answer/comment/discuss).

Along with sanctions against the user, do you think any action should be taken against the question?

Answer (score 4):

> What should responsible moderators not do with their power? What behavior have you disliked in moderators (on any SE or elsewhere) that you vow you'll never do?

<sub>[Copied from Anime & Manga's 2015 Mod Election](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2524/20275)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

A question was asked [a while back](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4314/48808) about lowering the close vote threshold from 5 to 3. Since moderator support for such a move is critical, do you think the current threshold is fine or should it be lowered, and why?

Comment: I'm glad you added this into the pool. One of my answers was going to briefly touch this topic, but now I can expand on it more :)

Answer (score 2):

> You (a moderator) and another community member both answer a question on the site. The other answer is well written but (objectively) incorrect, and has gathered a similar amount of upvotes to yours. What do you do?

<sub>[Copied from Arqade's 2019 Mod Election](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13376/124566)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

- Where do you want to see the site and/or community go in the near future?
- Where *don't* you want to see it go?
- (Optional: Provide the rationale behind your decisions.)

Answer (score 1):

The community as a whole has many things that are can be seen as lack, underdeveloped, or could use further development, compared to other sites or communities (such as our sister sites within the some category).

- What do you see as the top three immediate things that you would like to tackle as moderator that you cannot do as a user.
- Why do you think these points are important and should be prioritized?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like [Senshin's question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4070/20275) from the 2017 Mod election is still applicable today, with slight modifications.

How much do you know about the following series: *Naruto*, *One Piece,* *My Hero Academia*, and *Attack on Titan*?

These series are some of the [top tags as of 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1310219/2020-anime-manga-top-questions) that I see more of than others. To date, I still see many (mostly poorly written) questions regarding the *Naruto* series despite it officially coming to an end in 2017. And as far as I can tell, My Hero Academia and Attack on Titan are becoming more popular as the days go by.

As Senshin also posted as well:`

> Knowing about these series is by no means a requirement, of course. But if candidates A and B are identical except that A has an encyclopedic knowledge of Naruto while B has an encyclopedic knowledge of (say) Doraemon, I would vote for A.

Comment: I don't necessarily think that a moderator needs to be specialized towards the particular top tags is as important nowadays. As we've seen thru the years paradigms shift as do the taste and interest of audience. A good generalist mentality to cover many based can be more beneficial than a specialist one in fewer areas. Being able to reach out or defer to other mods or users for the knowledge or expertise you can make way for a better balancing of priorities. Being polarized to certain tags over others might cause other areas to be neglected.

Comment: @кяαzєя That is a good point, I didn't looked at it from that perspective when submitting the question :) In the next 5 years, the top anime/manga could be completely different than what it is today